# I want to copy the content of 2 file into third file

Tags: java

I have  written code for one file content copy to another file. but i didn't able to copy second file content to third file .
for that i written following code :

```
    try {
        File infile = new File("d:\\vijay.txt");
        File outfile = new File("d:\\ajay.txt");

        FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(infile);
        FileOutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(outfile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int length;

        while ((length = instream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outstream.write(buffer, 0, length);

        }
        instream.close();
        outstream.close();

        System.out.println("File Copied successfully");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Please help me ,Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was the problem? If you can do one you can do two just as easily. BTW You should fix your formatting, I suggest using your IDE.

Comment: You generally don't see writing to multiple files in the same way at the same time, because that is usually handled by calling the method multiple times with different output streams.  In other words, once you have a method that copies 1 file to another, you have a method that can copy 1 file many times or copy many files to one file or any combination thereof.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Java 7, I would suggest you use the `Files` utils.  For example:

```
Path source1 = Paths.get("src1.txt");
Path source2 = Paths.get("src2.txt");

Path destination = Paths.get("dest.txt");    
out = Files.newOutputStream(destination, CREATE, APPEND);

Files.copy(source1, destination, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
Files.copy(source2, destination);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it as below:

```
try {
    // the files to be copied
    String[] filePaths = {"file1.txt", "file2.txt"};
    // out file
    File outfile = new File("d:\\ajay.txt");
    FileOutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(outfile);

    // loop to all files copied
    for (String filePath : filePaths) {
        FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = instream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outstream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        // close each file on copy finished
        instream.close();
    }
    // at the end close the output stream
    outstream.close();
    System.out.println("File Copied successfully");
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now you can copy n files to one file.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
try {
            File infile = new File("/home/bobo/test/a.txt");
            File infile1 = new File("/home/bobo/test/b.txt");

            //The third file
            File outfile = new File("/home/bobo/test/c.txt");

            FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(infile);
            FileInputStream instream1 = new FileInputStream(infile1);

            FileOutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(outfile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int length;

            while ((length = instream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outstream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            while ((length = instream1.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outstream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            instream.close();
            instream1.close();
            outstream.close();

            System.out.println("File Copied successfully");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

just give it a try

```
public class Filescombining
{
       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
       {      
       ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
       try
       {
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( "input1.txt"));
         BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( "input2.txt"));
            String s1 =null;
            String s2 = null;

                         while ((s1 = br.readLine()) != null)
                         {                         
                                        list.add(s1);        
                         }
                         while((s2 = r.readLine()) != null)
                         {    
                                        list.add(s2);    
                         } 
       }
        catch (IOException e)
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

           BufferedWriter writer=null;
           writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
            String listWord;              
                   for (int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++)
                  {
                        listWord = list.get(i);
                       writer.write(listWord);
                       writer.write("\n");
                  }
                           System.out.println("completed");
                           writer.close();    
        }
    }
```

hope my help works happy coding

Comment: Did you create a random number generator to indent your code?  How can you work like that?

Comment: it is appending after first file completed copying